# How to do a 3D plot using R?

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot a 3D plot using R. My data set is independent, which means the values of x, y, and z are not dependent on each other. The plot I want is given in this picture:

[image: Three dimensional plot]

This plot was drawn by someone using MATLAB. How can I can do the same kind of Plot using R?

Comment: try `lattice::cloud` to make a 3d scatterplot. also try posting some sample data here.

Comment: erosion prec. uplift
17.79 42.22391855 0.154363636
15.33 42.22391855 0.154363636
19.89 42.22391855 0.154363636
20.52 41.4402374 0.154363636
16.68 41.4402374 0.154363636
10.35 42.22391855 0.154363636
21.88 41.4402374 0.154363636
22.62 42.22391855 0.154363636
23.42 42.22391855 0.154363636
16.95 42.22391855 0.154363636
18.51 42.22391855 0.154363636
19.98 42.22391855 0.154363636
16.76 41.4402374 0.154363636
17.28 41.4402374 0.238545455

Comment: You could also try out the following `plotly` package in R.
Take a look at the second example at this link.
https://plot.ly/r/line-and-scatter/#adding-color-and-size-mapping

Answer (score 2):

Since you posted your image file, it appears you are not trying to make a 3d scatterplot, rather a 2d scatterplot with a continuous color scale to indicate the value of a third variable.

Option 1: For this approach I would use `ggplot2`

```
# make data
mydata <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100, 10, 3),
                     y = rnorm(100, 5, 10),
                     z = rpois(100, 20))
ggplot(mydata, aes(x,y)) + geom_point(aes(color = z)) + theme_bw()
```

Which produces:
[image]

Option 2: To make a 3d scatterplot, use the `cloud` function from the `lattice` package.

```
library(lattice)
# make some data
x <- runif(20)
y <- rnorm(20)
z <- rpois(20, 5) / 5
cloud(z ~ x * y)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi,
Thanks but need more help. how can i make it colourful and how do i set the range of my Z values

Answer (score 0):

I usually do these kinds of plots with the base plotting functions and some helper functions for the color levels and color legend from the [sinkr](https://github.com/marchtaylor/sinkr) package (you need the devtools package to install from GitHib).

#### Example:

```
#library(devtools)
#install_github("marchtaylor/sinkr")
library(sinkr)

# example data
grd <- expand.grid(
  x=seq(nrow(volcano)),
  y=seq(ncol(volcano))
)
grd$z <- c(volcano)

# plot
COL <- val2col(grd$z, col=jetPal(100))

op <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
layout(matrix(1:2,1,2), widths=c(4,1), heights=4)
par(mar=c(4,4,1,1))
plot(grd$x, grd$y, col=COL, pch=20)
par(mar=c(4,1,1,4))
imageScale(grd$z, col=jetPal(100), axis.pos=4)
mtext("z", side=4, line=3)
par(op)
```

#### Result:

[image]